# I feed my cats wet food in tthe AM and PM and they always have dry food is that OK

Tags: cats, feeding

I feed my cats wet food 2 times a day and they always have dry food....am I feeding them too much?
Do I feed my cats too much?

Comment: are they overweight?

Comment: please give more details,is your cats neutered/spayed-indoor/outdoor cats-indoor only.is the dry food formulated for the age of your cats and if your cats is spayed/neutered is the food formulated for this.